# addToBackStack for fragment in Android

Tags: android, fragment

Say I have an activity and there are two placeholder in the view:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout id="fg_1" ...>
    <RelativeLayout id="fg_2  ...>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now once something happened I will add a fragment to the view by these codes:

```
private void showFragment(Fragment fragment, int id) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(id, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

For example, when I trigger action 1, the Fragment1 will show, when trigger action2 Fragment2 will show.

Now when I click the back menu, in my opinion, the Fragment2 will disappear, and when I click back menu again, the Fragment1 will disappear, and the app will exit once I click back menu again.

However the app will exit even I click the back menu once, it seems that the `addToBackStack` does not work as I expected.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say that you have to replace with same container.

Here you have taken 2 Relative layout as container.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout id="fg_1" ...>
    <RelativeLayout id="fg_2  ...>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Which should be like

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout id="fg_1" ...>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Replace your fragment with 1 Relative layout ( **fg_1** ) container.

Let me know for the same if any issue.

Hope it will help you.

**Edit:**

Make sure you are using same FragmentManager, same Fragment. Means I have faced same issue before 2 months that I have used **android.app.FragmentManager** in **one** class and and **android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager** in **other** class.

May be it would be help you.

Comment: Does not work, I trigger the action2 twice, which means show the fragment2 at the same container twice, however once I press the back, the app exit

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `addBackStack(null)` method from your code. after click on back press to exit the app.

```
private void showFragment(Fragment fragment, int id) 
{
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(id, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```